# Does the abelian group in the definition of a left R-module need to be additive?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring and $M$ an abelian group, a left $R$ module consists of the aforementioned abelian group $M$ and an operation $f:R \times M\rightarrow{M}$ satisfying for $r,s\epsilon{R}$ and $x,y\epsilon{M}$

$r(x+y)=rx+ry$

$(r+s)x=rx+sx$

$(rs)x=r(sx)$

$1_{R}x=x$ if $R$ is unital

The Wikipedia article uses the notation $(M,+)$ for $M$ and the encyclopedia of mathematics page explicitly says that $M$ is additive while other sources make no mention of the binary operation in $M$. So does $M$ need to be additive or can it be multiplicative?

Comment: The group law on the underlying abelian group can certainly either be additive or multiplicative. Usually for modules, we always write the group operation additively and the 'scalar multiplication' multiplicatively so as not to confuse them.

Comment: Completely slipped my mind that the multiplication is scalar multiplication, it actually makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: The field $\mathbb{R}$ acts on the multiplicative group of strictly positive real numbers, $\mathbb{R}_+$, by the operation $(\lambda, x) \mapsto x^\lambda$, making $\mathbb{R}_+$ into a one-dimensional real vector space, so this is a very common everyday instance where the "addition" in the module is customarily written multiplicatively.

Comment: "Additive" and "multiplicative" abelian groups are just notational conventions. They aren't two different kinds of mathematical objects.

Comment: Also, if $M$ is any abelian group whatsoever, you can (as Qiaochu Yuan has just pointed out) write it multiplicatively, and then you can take $R = \mathbb{Z}$, when the operation $R \times M \to M$, $(n, x) \mapsto x^n$ makes $M$ into a $\mathbb{Z}$-module in the usual way.

Comment: A very accessible and useful example. Thanks